# How to put quotation marks around all parts of a Google Sheets formula that are not cell references

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to be able to see my formulas with actual data in them to help with troubleshooting.

So I want to get a regular expression that will put quotation marks around all non-cell-reference items.

I tried

**Original formula**

```
=IFERROR(
 (($Q10*24*Q$2)*($O10*$O$2)*( ($T10+$V10)*$S$2)*($P10*$P$2))/($R10*$R$2),"Spec missing")
```

**Desired output**

```
="IFERROR(
 (("&$Q10&"*24*"&Q$2&")*("&$O10&"*"&$O$2&")*( ("&$T10&"+"&$V10&")*"&$S$2&")*("&$P10&"*"&$P$2&"))/("&$R10&"*"&$R$2&"),""Spec missing"")"
```

When I copy the output and paste as text, I want to get a formula in the cell that outputs text looks like this:

```
="IFERROR(
 ((0.363194444444444*24*1)*(17348*1)*( (4.096+18.874368)*1)*(2519*1))/(3*1),""Spec missing"")"
```

- I can then copy that down and that helps me troubleshoot the formula (or the data) if something weird is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found:

*I copy the formula and paste it in F10 (with an ' in front of it so it comes up as a text string), then paste the following:*

```
="="""&REGEXREPLACE(regexreplace(F2,"\""","\""\"""),"(\$?[A-Z]{1,2}\$?\d+)","""&$1&""")&""""
```

*Description: i) The first regexreplace (going from innermost to outermost) I use to escape all the quotes in the formula by replacing all double quotes with two double quotes, so that quotes in the original formula won't mess things up.  ii) The second REGEXREPplace finds things that match the "$A1" (or "A1" or "A$1") pattern, allowing up to two letters (eg. "AA1" will work as well).  iii) I put "="""& before and &"""" and after to finish the formula.*

One problem I still have with this setup is that it doesn't handle cell references in another worksheet, such as "Rankings!A1".  I'm not sure what sort of regular expression I'd be able to use that could match everything before the "!" that could be part of a sheet name without starting to match other things . . .